# What types of functions in Joomla are analogous to Drupal hooks?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, module, plugin

Drupal has many hooks, such as hook_menu and hook_form. What are some functions in Joomla analogous to these?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve on your Joomla site, then we'll be able to give you more of a definitive answer

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal, a "hook can be thought of as an event listener in the sense that an event triggers an action" (see https://www.drupal.org/node/292  for a more detailed explanation).

In Joomla, I think the closest equivalent would be a "plugin". Plugins are also triggered by events. You can find a list of plugin events at: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events